# An unknown combinatorial optimization problem

Tags: optimization, np-complete, combinatorics

I have $N$ available sensors and $M$ devices. Each device needs $a$ sensors. One sensor cannot be used on multiple devices. Each sensor has two properties defined by $H$ and $R$.

Let $\sigma_{i\_H}$ be the standard deviation of property $H$ for sensors on device $i$. Similarly, $\sigma_{i\_R}$ is the standard deviation of property $R$ for sensors on device $i$.

Now let $s_{H}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{M} \sigma_{i\_H}^2 }$ of all devices for the $H$ property. And $s_{R}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{M} \sigma_{i\_R}^2 }$ of all devices for the $R$ property.

The goal is to minimize $\mu=\frac{s_H + s_R}{2}$ .

Looking for guidance on which type of optimization problem this might be and for inspiration for different search algorithms.

Comment: (I started musing about *super-linear* & *sub-linear*.)

Comment: One possible approach would be to use a [local search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(optimization)) method, such as simulated annealing.

Comment: If I did not miss something, had you only one property H and N=Ma, the law of total variance would say that it's best to simply sort the sensors according to H and then  split it into the M groups.

Comment: With both R & H maybe this could get you to some variant of a clustering problem in the plane..